# Why doesn't "use lib" take effect in this way?

Tags: perl

In my app, I put all the modules in one directory , let's just call it  `libx`.
Since it's up to the user to choose where to deploy the app, I don't want to hardcode the `lib` path.

So at the beginning of `myapp.pl`, I wrote the following lines of code.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $curr_dir = $0;
my $curr_lib = $curr_dir;
$curr_lib =~ s/myapp\.pl/libx/;

use $curr_lib ;
```

Instead of getting what I'm expecting, I got compiling errors!

So what's wrong with my code? I don't want to  hardcode the lib path when using `use lib`, how should I do this?

---

Sorry I forgot to mention that when the app is deployed, `myapp.pl` and `libx` are in the same directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use happens at compile-time, not run-time, so your variable hasn't been set yet.
You can do:

```
my $curr_lib;
BEGIN {
    $curr_lib = $0;
    $curr_lib =~ s/myapp\.pl/libx/;
}    
use lib $curr_lib;
```

or you could:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/libx";
```

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with this before too. What's happening is that Perl makes two passes over your code: once to compile it, and the second time to run it. In you example, lines 4,5, and 6 don't execute until run time, but `use` takes effect during compile time.

One possibility is to put it all inside a `BEGIN{}` block, which will make the code execute at compile time. I've done this, but it's messy/ugly. (BTW, instead of `$0`, you need to use `$ARGV[0]` in Perl).

The best way to tell Perl where to pick up libraries is to use the `-I` flag. You can put it on the `#!` line, or if you are starting the script from another script, you can start it as

```
perl -I/your/directory/libx your_script.pl
```

You *can* use relative paths, so maybe

```
perl -I./libx script.pl
```

would work for you.

Comment: It would help if you told us exactly how you expect your user to start the app. Will they just type 'myapp.pl', and it's up to them to have $PATH set so that myapp.pl can be found in whatever directory they stuck it?

Answer (score 1):

`use xxx` is a *compile-time* directive, not a run-time instruction. You cannot set it programmatically within the script you are running.

You may need to try [require rather than use](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html)

If you need `use`, you need to set your `$PERL5LIB` environment variable to ensure your modules are correctly located and used, or change your shebang line to read `#! /usr/local/perl -w -I/path/to/libx`. There are other methods (`local::lib` etc.), but from your question it seems your control over installation is a bit limited for that sort of approach.

Comment: This not 100% true, you can use a string `eval` to execute a `use` at runtime.